# my edit button doesnt work on the next page (only work on the first page)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

my edit and delete query only work on the first page of datatables, but not on the second page.
i'm using ajax and jquery. i'm new and this is for my project in college. thanks for helping me.
here's the code.

```js
 <script>
       $(function () {
    $("#example1").DataTable();
    $('#example2').DataTable({
      "paging": true,
      "lengthChange": false,
      "searching": false,
      "ordering": true,
      "info": true,
      "autoWidth": false
    });
  });

    </script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function (){
        $(".open_modal").click(function (e){
          var m = $(this).attr("id");
          $.ajax({
            url: "user_edit.php",
            type: "GET",
            data : {username: m,},
            success: function (ajaxData){
              $("#ModalEdit").html(ajaxData);
              $("#ModalEdit").modal('show',{backdrop: 'true'});
            }
          });
        });
      });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function (){
      $(".open_delete").click(function (e){
        var m = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
          url: "user_delete.php",
          type: "GET",
          data : {username: m,},
          success: function (ajaxData){
            $("#ModalDelete").html(ajaxData);
            $("#ModalDelete").modal('show',{backdrop: 'true'});
          }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
```

```html
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tambah" class="btn btn-info"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Tambah User</button>
            </br>
            </br>

            <?php include"alert.php"; ?>
            <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped" >
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Nomor</th>
                  <th>Username</th>
                  <th>Nama Lengkap</th>
                  <th>Password</th>
                  <th>Level</th>
                  <th>Nama Toko</th>
                  <th>Action</th>   
                </tr>
              </thead>

              <tbody>
              <?php 
              include "connection.php";
              $query_mysql = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT username, password, level, nama_lengkap, status, nama_toko FROM master_user INNER JOIN master_toko ON master_user.id_toko = master_toko.id_toko where status='0'")or die(mysqli_error());

              $nomor = 1;
              while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query_mysql)){
                ?>
                  <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $nomor++; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $data['username']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $data['nama_lengkap']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $data['password']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $data['level']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $data['nama_toko']; ?></td>
                    <td>
                      <a href="#" class='btn btn-primary open_modal' id='<?php echo $data['username']; ?>'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="padding-right: 2px"></span>Edit</a> |
                      <a href="#" class='btn btn-danger open_delete' id='<?php echo $data['username']; ?>'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="padding-right: 2px"></span>Hapus</a>        
                    </td>
                  </tr>  <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
               
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    
   <!-- FOR EDIT AND DELETE -->
    <div id="ModalEdit" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    </div>

    <div id="ModalDelete" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    </div>
```

and this is for edit 
i reference the username because username is my primary key
here the code

```html
    include "connection.php";
    $username = $_GET['username'];
    echo $username;
    $ambildata = mysqli_query($connection,"select * from master_user where username='$username'");
    
    while($row=  mysqli_fetch_array($ambildata)){
?>

<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit User</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal" action="proses_edituser.php" name="modal-popup" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" id="form-edit">
           
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class=" control-label col-md-3">Username</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $row['username']; ?>"/>
                            
                            <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                </div>
                            
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Nama Lengkap</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                       <input  class="form-control" type="text" name="nama_lengkap" value="<?php echo $row['nama_lengkap']; ?>"/>
                        <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                </div>
                            
                <div class="form-group">
                     <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Password</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $row['password']; ?>"/>
            </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Level</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                             <select name="level" class="form-control">
                                          <option value=''>--Select--</option>
                                          <option value='owner' <?php if ($row['level']=='owner'){echo"SELECTED";}?>>Owner</option>
                                          <option value='manajer' <?php if($row['level'] == 'manajer'){ echo "SELECTED"; } ?>>Manajer</option>
                                          <option value='bendahara' <?php if($row['level'] == 'bendahara'){ echo "SELECTED"; } ?> >Bendahara</option>
                                          <option value='administrator' <?php if($row['level'] == 'administrator'){ echo "SELECTED"; } ?>>Administrator</option>
                                      </select>
                            <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                </div>

                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Toko</label>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                      <select name="id_toko" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">-- Pilih Toko --</option>
                        <?php
                          require "connection.php";
                          $datatoko = "SELECT * FROM master_toko ORDER BY id_toko ASC";
                          $resultsql = mysqli_query($connection, $datatoko);
                          if (mysqli_num_rows($resultsql) > 0) {
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultsql)) {
                             
                             echo "<option value='$row[id_toko]'>$row[nama_toko]</option>";

                             // $nama_toko = $row['nama_toko'];
                              //echo '<option value="'.$row['id_toko'].'">'. $nama_toko.'</option>';
                            }
                          }        
                      ?>
                    </select>
                    
                  </div>
                </div>
              
    
    
      <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Simpan"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved" style="padding-right: 2px"></span>Simpan</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-remove" style="padding-right: 2px"></span>Batal</button>                
            </div>
            </form>
    
            <?php
    }
            ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You cannot add your PHP code into Stack Fiddle. only HTML, JS, CSS code you able to put on Fiddle.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Also, be warned that your queries are widely open for SQL injection - have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because the html for these buttons are rendered again & previous event attached to these are not found. So you need to add the events for newly elements also. One good solution is to use jQuery [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to attach the event on dynamic elements as well. Use the below code to check

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function (){
        $("body").on('click', '.open_modal', function (e){
          var m = $(this).attr("id");
          $.ajax({
            url: "user_edit.php",
            type: "GET",
            data : {username: m,},
            success: function (ajaxData){
              $("#ModalEdit").html(ajaxData);
              $("#ModalEdit").modal('show',{backdrop: 'true'});
            }
          });
        });
      });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function (){
      $("body").on('click', '.open_delete', function (e){
        var m = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
          url: "user_delete.php",
          type: "GET",
          data : {username: m,},
          success: function (ajaxData){
            $("#ModalDelete").html(ajaxData);
            $("#ModalDelete").modal('show',{backdrop: 'true'});
          }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: thank you for helping me :)) @AgamBanga ! it really works and your explanation really help me to study more on programming. thank you so  much. i vote you

Comment: i wanna ask you again, i use username as my primary key and there is a bug after it because i cant edit my username in that form. and the question is, how can i get the old values of my username so when i edit the data, the query like "update master_user set username = ((($newusername)) where username = ((($oldusername)))" ?thanks @AgamBanga

Comment: @natalieglo you want to update the `username` on condition of `username` ?

Comment: yeah, can i? or should i add a id? i try it to phpmyadmin and it works.. but not in my program ._. @AgamBanga

Comment: @natalieglo the best approach is to use autoincrement id as your primary key and update that according to id. But it should be working fine with the username as well. can you show me the php code for updation?

Comment: <?php
       include "connection.php";
     $username    = $_POST['username'];
     $nama_lengkap     = $_POST['nama_lengkap'];
     $password   = $_POST['password'];
     $level    = $_POST['level'];
     $id_toko   = $_POST['id_toko'];

 
  $ambildata = mysqli_query($connection, "update master_user set username='$username', nama_lengkap='$nama_lengkap', password=md5('$password'), level='$level', status='0', id_toko='$id_toko' where username='$username' ");
     header('location:listadmin.php?code=2');
 
?>

Comment: like that ._. @AgamBanga

Comment: try printing this `if (!$ambildata) { echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($connection));}` after the `mysqli_query` command @natalieglo