# my edit/delete buttons does not work on other pages like next page on the table. it only work on the first page with 10 data entries

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, database

my edit and delete query only work on the first page of datatables, but not on the second page. i'm using ajax and jquery. thanks for helping me. here is the code:

```
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="text-center">#</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Product Info</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php 
                            $i = 1;
                            $prod = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM product_list order by id asc");
                            while($row=$prod->fetch_assoc()):
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="text-center"><?php echo $i++ ?></td>
                                <td class="">

                                    <p><small>Category : <b><?php echo $cat_arr[$row['category_id']] ?></b></small></p>
                                    <p><small>Name : <b><?php echo $row['name'] ?></b></small></p>
                                    <p><small>Description : <b><?php echo $row['description'] ?></b></small></p>
                                    <p><small>Price : <b><?php echo number_format($row['price'],2) ?></b></small></p>
                                    <p><small>Expiry Date : <b><?php echo $row['expdate'] ?></b></small></p>
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-center">
                                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary edit_product" type="button" data-id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" data-name="<?php echo $row['name'] ?>" data-sku="<?php echo $row['sku'] ?>" data-category_id="<?php echo $row['category_id'] ?>" data-description="<?php echo $row['description'] ?>" data-price="<?php echo $row['price'] ?>" data-cprice="<?php echo $row['cprice'] ?>" data-pdate="<?php echo $row['pdate'] ?>" data-expdate="<?php echo $row['expdate'] ?>">Edit</button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger delete_product" type="button" data-id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">Delete</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-4">
        <form action="" id="manage-product">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                       Wholesale Stocks 
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Ref No:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sku" value="<?php echo $sku ?>">
                        </div>                          
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Category</label>
                            <select name="category_id" id="" class="custom-select browser-default">
                            <?php 

                            $cat = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM category_list order by name asc");
                            while($row=$cat->fetch_assoc()):
                                $cat_arr[$row['id']] = $row['name'];
                            ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"><?php echo $row['name'] ?></option>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Product Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Description</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" cols="30" rows="3" name="description"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Cost Price</label>
                        <input type="number" step="any" class="form-control text-right" name="cprice" >
                    </div>                      
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Selling Price</label>
                        <input type="number" step="any" class="form-control text-right" name="price" >
                    </div>  
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Date Produced</label>
                        <input type="text" step="any" class="form-control text-right" name="pdate" >
                    </div>  
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Expiring Date</label>
                        <input type="text" step="any" class="form-control text-right" name="expdate" >
                    </div>                      
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary col-sm-3 offset-md-3"> Save</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary col-sm-3" type="button" onclick="$('#manage-product').get(0).reset()"> Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

This is the JQuery script. i used id as my primary key. here is the code

```
$('table').dataTable()
$('#manage-product').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    start_load()
    $.ajax({
        url:'ajax.php?action=save_product',
        data: new FormData($(this)[0]),
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        method: 'POST',
        type: 'POST',
        success:function(resp){
            if(resp==1){
                alert_toast("Data successfully added",'success')
                setTimeout(function(){
                    location.reload()
                },1500)

            }
            else if(resp==2){
                alert_toast("Data successfully updated",'success')
                setTimeout(function(){
                    location.reload()
                },1500)

            }
        }
    })
})
```

here is the edit function:

```
$('.edit_product').click(function(){
    start_load()
    var cat = $('#manage-product')
    cat.get(0).reset()
    cat.find("[name='id']").val($(this).attr('data-id'))
    cat.find("[name='name']").val($(this).attr('data-name'))
    cat.find("[name='sku']").val($(this).attr('data-sku'))
    cat.find("[name='category_id']").val($(this).attr('data-category_id'))
    cat.find("[name='description']").val($(this).attr('data-description'))
    cat.find("[name='price']").val($(this).attr('data-price'))
    cat.find("[name='cprice']").val($(this).attr('data-cprice'))
    cat.find("[name='pdate']").val($(this).attr('data-pdate'))
    cat.find("[name='expdate']").val($(this).attr('data-expdate'))
    end_load()
})
```

here is the delete function:

```
$('.delete_product').click(function(){
    _conf("Are you sure to delete this product?","delete_product",[$(this).attr('data-id')])
})
function delete_product($id){
    start_load()
    $.ajax({
        url:'ajax.php?action=delete_product',
        method:'POST',
        data:{id:$id},
        success:function(resp){
            if(resp==1){
                alert_toast("Data successfully deleted",'success')
                setTimeout(function(){
                    location.reload()
                },1500)

            }
        }
    })
}
```

for example, when i click edit, the form should be populated with the corresponding data displaying on the table and same case for the delete button which should return a dialogue message if i want to delete the data
i want the edit/delete buttons to work please, Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [my edit button doesnt work on the next page (only work on the first page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44039469/my-edit-button-doesnt-work-on-the-next-page-only-work-on-the-first-page)

Comment: Although they are similar questions but have different approach in implementation and as such i can not use the answer that worked there to figure out mine. And note he was calling a modal form while mine is in same page edit. thanks

Comment: The question headlines are same but the implementations are quite different. Just take a look at my Edit and delete codes above and you will agree with me. Any help from here to get this working will be appreciated.

Comment: I have sorted the question above. Thanks but i did not follow the solutions given in the answered. I implemented it entirely in another way and it gave me what i want.